# How do I get blender's pip to ignore system python's site_packages?

Tags: python

Please read carefully: this is not about *installing* packages with Blender's python, but rather ther reverse - ignoring system packages.

When I try to install packages with the pip I installed under Blender, I get messages such as

```
Requirement already satisfied: svgpathtools in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.6.1)
```

however Blender's python then doesn't find them when executing scripts.

How do I get Blender's pip to **ignore** system python's site_packages?

Right now I am working around this by renaming site_packages, but that's horrible and time consuming.

BTW, this seems new to Blender 3.4 (but no guarantee about that).

This is the command I use:

```
simone$ /home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/bin/pip install scikit-learn
```

and this the output I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.3.2 in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.1.1 in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /home/simone/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (3.1.0)
```

and the same results come if I use

```
simone$ /home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/bin/python3.10 -m pip install scikit-learn
```

and this is the screenshot of my preferences:

[image]

with no trace of extra/strange paths being added in.

I've also recursively looked for the string `site-packages` in my `.config/blender` directory and found nothing suspicious - except in dream-textures.

Answer (score 1):

I think it *is* an installing issue, not a force-ignore issue.

When you run the *pip install* with Blender's bundled pip, it still attempts to install the packages in your system's default python folder. You should tell pip where they'll be installed- specifically, Blender's Python's *site-packages* folder.

Your command will look something like this:

```
/home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/bin/pip install scikit-learn --target=/home/simone/blender/blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/3.4/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```